# Can't install any program on b+

Tags: software-installation

I tried to install geany on the raspberry pi type b+ with:

```
sudo apt-get -f install geany
```

but we get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 geany : Depends: geany-common (= 1.22+dfsg-2) but it is not going to
be installed
 pinta : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libglib2.0-cil (>= 2.12.10-1ubuntu1) but it is not
going to be installed
         Depends: libgtk2.0-cil (>= 2.12.10-1ubuntu1) but it is not
going to be installed
         Depends: libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil (>= 0.6) but it is not
going to be installed
         Depends: libmono-addins0.2-cil (>= 0.6) but it is not going
to be installed
         Depends: libmono-cairo4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going
to be installed
         Depends: libmono-corlib4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not
going to be installed
         Depends: libmono-posix4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going
to be installed
         Depends: libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not
going to be installed
         Depends: libmono-system-core4.0-cil (>= 2.10.3) but it is not
going to be installed
         Depends: libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not
going to be installed
         Depends: libmono-system4.0-cil (>= 2.10.7) but it is not
going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or
specify a solution).
```

and we also get it for other programs like java.

what does this mean? how to fix it?

ps. I am totaly new to raspberry pi.

Comment: Firstly Do: apt-get -f install; apt-get update; apt-get upgrade

Comment: As RahulAN says, try `sudo apt-get upgrade` then `sudo apt-get update` and indicate whether that worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

As RahulAN and goldilocks suggested:
Use `sudo apt-get update` to update repository first, and then do `sudo apt-get upgrade` to update package to latest version. After that you can install anything as long it have dependency on repository. You might do `sudo apt-get -f install` to fix your beforehand software installation before installing another software with `apt-get install`